# Excel: Referencing cells if two different cells match.

Tags: excel-formula

I will be as complete as I can be.

I have an Excel Workbook that contains 4 sheets.

Sheet 1.
Column F contains Computer Serial Numbers.

Sheet 4. 
Column A contains Computer Serial Numbers. 
Column H contains Building Numbers. 
Column I contains Room Numbers.

What I want to do is within sheet 1 column H for the building numbers to start.

I want to take a serial number in Sheet 1:F and look for that same serial number in Sheet 4:A. If it finds it, within the same row that it finds it, I want it to look in the H column for the building number and put that back in sheet 1.

If that makes sense.

Comment: VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the formula according to your description:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet4!H:H,MATCH(Sheet1!F1,Sheet4!A:A,0)),"Not found")
```

Comment: It is returning #N/A. My formula is as follows: =INDEX('ASSET LIST'!H2:H1626, MATCH('CONSOLIDATED LIST'!F2,'ASSET LIST'!A2:A1626,0))

Comment: It will if it cant find it, I added error exception.

Comment: Interesting. I don't know if I was concise enough in my original question? I have Serial Numbers on the sheet "Consolidated List". There should be matching Serial Numbers on the sheet "Asset List". And in the same row as the serial numbers on the sheet "Asset List" there are also Building numbers. I want to display the Bldg numbers in "Consolidated List".

Comment: This formula does exactly that but it might be that your numbers are not in same format, on may be text or something similar...

Comment: Okay, should I convert the entire sheets to numbers or text?

Comment: Try numbers, cant tell cuz I haven't seen your sheet :)

Comment: If I have a formula for Column F to get those values on Consolidated List, would that cause the error?